# Bootstrap input-group not responsive after making changes

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am working on a website, which is using Bootstrap 4. In this, I am facing the responsive issues as follows:

In my website, I have a search box and company name and my cart box as look like in the image. (in a maximized window)

[image]

When I reduce the browser window size it changes to:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-3">
        <br>

        <div class="input-group ">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." >
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text" >
              <i class="fas fa-search text-success" style="font-size:40px"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="assets/Images/Carousel Images/Abro.png" routerLink="/landingpage" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <br>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag text-primary" style="font-size:40px"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" value="My Cart ({{nCount}})" readonly>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Well, the first problem I can spot is the order of container and your first div with class="col-sm-12". Always first the container and then its content.

Comment: The columns are too small to fit screen width. When that happens they wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bootstrap input-group not responsive

That's because **you aren't using responsive classes**.

You are using classes like `col-3`, `col-1` and `col-4`.

Those classes literally mean:

> "Keep this column 3 units wide, 1 unit wide, 4 units wide etc starting from the smallest screens and on."

So, at any screen size, your columns will take up exactly the specified number of units. In other words, Bootstrap is behaving exactly as expected because you haven't specified/added any responsive column classes.

On the smallest screen (inside a container), 3 units will roughly result in 73px. So, on the smallest screen, your `col-3` column will be only 73px wide and if you take 15px of padding on each side into account, then you really don't have much space left for any content.

Docs for responsive grid and column layout:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

And:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Comment: The asker clearly states Bootstrap 4! You are referencing version 3, and they are not the same.

Comment: Just replace the @ with your font awesome icon in a span tag.